# recycler view with multiple item marquee

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-recyclerview

i have a recycler view having item xml like this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:background="@color/lightblue2"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/rlTickerItem"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvCompanySymbol"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="symbol"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:textColor="@color/darkGray"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/ask"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvCompanySymbol"
    android:id="@+id/ask"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
    android:textColor="@color/blueButton"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ask"
    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:id="@+id/tvAskAmount"
    android:textColor="@color/blueButton"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/bid"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvAskAmount"
    android:id="@+id/bid"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
    android:textColor="@color/red"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/bid"
    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:paddingEnd="4dp"
    android:id="@+id/tvBidAmount"
    android:textColor="@color/red"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

i need to make this recycler view marquee and ellipsize like a textview to scroll horizontally like ticker of news
i put for every textview

```
                android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

and  `setselected(true)` from the adapter and not working

Comment: Try adding android:focusable="true"

Comment: for what? textview or recycler view?

Comment: For your TextView

Comment: so for every textview must add focusable true

Comment: Try, I'm not sure if it'll work.. I'm replicating your code on a Test Project to figure it out.

Comment: okat thx, but not working , recycler view not scrolling

Comment: You want to marquee all items of the recycler view. there will be one view visible at a time?

Comment: i need to create a ticker that scroll horizontaly for ever like a single textview having marquee ='for ever'

Answer (score 2):

here,it's work fine in recyclerview:https://blog.csdn.net/tiantaiaiqing/article/details/79200299

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:textSize="12dp" />
```

//in recyckerview textView.setSelected(true)

```
holder.titleTv.setSelected(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it programmatically in **onBindViewHolder** of RecyclerView adapter :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Employees employee = mEmployees.get(position);
    holder.txt_name.setText(employee.get_name());
    holder.txt_name.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(2);
    holder.txt_name.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
    holder.txt_name.setSingleLine(true);
    holder.txt_name.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
    holder.txt_name.setSelected(true);
}
```